# Python CSV reader shall raise error upon wrong input

Tags: python, csv, exception

I have a string called `group_data`, which I want to read with Python's `csv.reader`. This is the call I am making.

```
group = csv.reader(group_data.split('\n'), delimiter=';', 
                   doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, strict=True)
```

I want that this raises an exception whenever one of the following is the case:

- There is a single quote: `"A";"B "bb" B";"C"` instead
  of `"A";"B ""bb"" B";"C")`
- Any of the fields is not
  quoted: `A;B;C` instead of `"A";"B";"C"`

However, the excerpt above accepts both lines as correct, even with the `doublequote=True`, `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`, and `strict=True` settings. Is there another option I should set to make it fail? If this is not possible, is there another way to quickly notice if there is a single quote or an unquoted field?

Comment: [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) has a [csv reader](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table).  It may be worth checking if their reader is a little more strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, it looks like Python 3.4 does reject your first example:

```
In [8]: mkreader = lambda x: csv.reader(x.split("\n"), delimiter=";", doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, strict=True)
In [11]: for l in mkreader('''"A";"B ""bb"" B";"C"'''): print(l)
['A', 'B "bb" B', 'C']
In [12]: for l in mkreader('''"A";"B "bb" B";"C"'''): print(l)
...
Error: ';' expected after '"'
```

Although it allows the second:

```
In [13]: for l in mkreader('''A;B;C'''): print(l)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params), it seems like this is because `QUOTE_ALL` is strictly a writer setting, not a reader setting:

```
csv.QUOTE_ALL
    Instructs writer objects to quote all fields.
```

Compare to:

```
csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC

    Instructs writer objects to quote all non-numeric fields.

    Instructs the reader to convert all non-quoted fields to type float.
```

So it looks like you need to make this yourself if you want it. This is simple if you know that `;` will never appear inside your rows (which appears to be the case, since you don't set `escapechar`):

```
In [19]: def check_line(line):
    for word in line.split(';'):
        if word[0] != '"' or word[-1] != '"':
            raise csv.Error("Bad input.")
In [20]: check_line("A;B;C")
...
Error: Bad input.
```

Comment: I noticed that the reader command itself did not raise an error in the first case in Python 3.4, but when you then use that reader in a for loop, it does. I guess I have to build this second check manually. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be more complicated than I hoped for, since I have to basically implement my own csv reader for it (split for newlines, then split for semicolons, then check quotes).